# Art works with 'no date'

Tags: abbreviations

I am an art historian from Denmark, and I have trouble with English abbreviations - I hope someone can help me.

I have a lithograph without date, how do I write 'undated'? (n.d.) ?

Best Diana

Comment: It is quite common to abbreviate a publication with no copyright date as (n.d.).       https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=oI1aLHbNmT4C&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=how+to+abbreviate+%22no+copyright+date%22&source=bl&ots=CmA5DV_UwA&sig=3UXla0e2Y76m7h7_S2raKUIHDj0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip1NqutonXAhVHLhoKHaf3D94Q6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20abbreviate%20%22no%20copyright%20date%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a style guide, follow it. If you're not, then I would use n.d. (which is pretty clear to me and happens to be what some style guides use):

> [APA](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/01/alphabetizing-in-press-and-no-date-references.html) (blog): Also remember that “no date” is abbreviated as “n.d.” in both the reference list and the in-text citations.

> [Chicago MoS](http://libanswers.snhu.edu/faq/129215): When the publication date of a printed work cannot be ascertained, the abbreviation *n.d.* takes the place of the year in the publication details.

However, there is really no standard, as you can find abbreviations such as [UD](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yk0PhyBTCXoC&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3) (undated) used too, if you look hard enough. Consider explaining your abbreviation somewhere for clarity.